# Jupyter Notebookを行ったら、以下の文が出てJupyterが起動できません。

Tags: jupyter-notebook

どなたか解決してくださる方いませんか。
macOSで実行しました。
文は以下の通りです。

```
[I 17:44:21.335 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[E 17:44:21.336 NotebookApp] Failed to write cookie secret to /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret'
[W 17:44:21.336 NotebookApp] Could not set permissions on /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:59: UserWarning: IPython dir '/Users/taka/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  warn("IPython dir '{0}' is not a writable location,"
[I 2022-01-16 17:44:21.723 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2022-01-16 17:44:21.723 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/taka
[I 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.5 is running at:
[I 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=143a87df2bc97f5dc4bc8afb6ba617fdcde91e214c69c2c5
[I 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=143a87df2bc97f5dc4bc8afb6ba617fdcde91e214c69c2c5
[I 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 17:44:21.728 NotebookApp] Failed to write server-info to /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16647.json: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16647.json'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-Notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2311, in start
    self.write_browser_open_file()
  File "/Users/taka/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2214, in write_browser_open_file
    with open(self.browser_open_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16647-open.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret: [Errno 13]　Permission denied:
>
> IPython dir '/Users/taka/.ipython' is not a writable location
>
> /Users/taka/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16647.json: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied:
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

わかりやすいエラーメッセージがたくさん出ています。
パーミッションエラー（書き込み権限がないエラー）になります。

インストール手順や操作方法が一切書かれていませんので、ここから想像できることは、
Anacondaをroot権限でインストールしてしまった。
または、jupyterをroot権限でインストールしてしまった。
そして、一般ユーザーでjupyterを実行しているので、書き込み権限が無いエラーが発生。
と想像できます。

一般ユーザーでもう一度Anacondaを再インストールするか、
root権限でchownコマンドで所有者を変更してみてください。